# How to use a sdk (non-ros header/lib/binaries) in ros package?

Tags: opencv, hardware, camera, 3rd-party-package, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use a camera sdk to write a camera stream publisher in ros.

It's not a uvc camera, so I cannot use usb_cam or other similar nodes to access the camera stream.

I've already had the camera sdk consisting of ASICamera.h/libASICamera.a/libASICamera.so, and I've successfully got it running.

But now I don't know how to use it in a ros node.

After I add the header files into the package/include directory

and #include "ASICamera.h" into the publisher node,

I type catkin_make. it reports:

make[2]: *** [asi_converter_real/CMakeFiles/asi_converter_real.dir/src/asi_converter_real.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [asi_converter_real/CMakeFiles/asi_converter_real.dir/all] Error 2

I think the reason is that I have not add the .a and .so into the publisher node.

But I don't know how to do this

In the package.xml, it seems that

build_depend and run_depend tags can only access ros-inbuilt static/dynamic libraries, how could I use my own .a and .so in a ros node ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198139/how-to-use-a-sdk-(non-ros-header/lib/binaries)-in-ros-package?/) by [fromandto](https://answers.ros.org/users/20325/fromandto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-11-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package.xml file only describes what the node depends on, so that catkin can figure out what packages to add during compilation. The real heart of the compiling system is **CMakeLists.txt**. There you'll list both the catkin packages and the non-catkin (system) packages. Your ASICamera.h falls in the second category.

Say you're building a node called **ros_asicamera**, and the asicamera library is called **asicamera.so**. Then your CMakeLists.txt will have something like:

```
add_executable( ros_asicamera src/ros_asicamera.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ros_asicamera asicamera)
```

Bare in mind that if asicamera header and libraries files are not installed in the default system paths (e.g. /usr/lib, /usr/local, /usr/include etc) then you have to tell CMake how to find them. This is done in several ways, depending on your asicamera package. The most portable ways are pkg-config or findAsicamera.cmake (the second is preferable). If these files are not provided then you can use:

```
include_directories(path_to_asicamera.h)
```

for the header files. Finding libraries is more tricky, and you can find additional information at http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries.

Last but not least, since the error message you posted is not very informative, try doing:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

to get additional information on the error. That also helps when posting on the Q/A.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fromandto](https://answers.ros.org/users/20325/fromandto/) on 2014-11-25**:
make VERBOSE=1 is very useful!!!!!! thx so much, Now I know that Makefile is in the ws/build, with VERBOSE I can find which header/library is missed and How the final -I/-l lines look like. thx again, lorenzo

**Comment by [farhad-bat](https://answers.ros.org/users/108560/farhad-bat/) on 2022-06-30**:
Hi,

I have a similar question,
https://answers.ros.org/question/403220/how-use-external-header-file-and-codes-in-ros-cmakelist/

I did what you said, however, new error happened:

```
lumenera_camera/lucam-sdk_2.4.3.94/api/include/lucommon.h:137:10: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
 #include <windows.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

**Comment by [farhad-bat](https://answers.ros.org/users/108560/farhad-bat/) on 2022-06-30**:
I have a problem that is similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72823620/use-sdk-libraries-header-files-etc-during-creating-a-c-ros-package